# Quickbook web connector error

Tags: quickbooks, qbwc

I am trying to connect quickbooks web connector with my php website. I have successfully integrated QWC file with it.

Here is the QWC file:

```xml
<QBWCXML>
    <AppName>QuickBooks Integrator</AppName>
    <AppID></AppID>
    <AppURL>https://domain.com/quick1/docs/example_web_connector.php</AppURL>
    <AppDescription>Test desktop quickbook</AppDescription>
    <AppSupport>http://domain.com/file.html</AppSupport>
    <UserName>mudit</UserName>
    <OwnerID>{90A44FB7-33D9-4815-AC85-AC86A7E7D1EB}</OwnerID>
    <FileID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4FCC-B1FF-967DE1813D20}</FileID>
    <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
    <Scheduler>
        <RunEveryNMinutes>2</RunEveryNMinutes>
    </Scheduler>
    <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
```

When I run this from web connector I get error `Last result: authentication failed`.

Below is a small snippet of error log:

```
For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-serverVersion.
20130628.20:14:55 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20130628.20:14:55 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.0.0.139">
20130628.20:14:56 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: <The request failed with the error message:
      <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
      <html><head>
      <title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
      </head><body>
      <h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
```

Comment: Is `<AppURL>https://domain.com/quick1/docs/example_web_connector.php</AppURL>` your actual qwc appurl?

Comment: yes..just replaced my actual domain name with "domain.com" here in the link

Comment: ok i just tried using my wampserver i.e localhost and all worked fine...so should i assume something is wrong with ssl of my website?

Comment: Do you get any browser errors when you try and go to your website on secure port? `https://yourdomain.com`.  Then yes.  The quickbooks webconnector doesn't allow connections if there is a cert problem on a public domain.  It assumes you're developing if it connects to localhost.

Comment: yes that was the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs are indicating that your AppURL is incorrect:

```
20130628.20:14:56 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: <The request failed with the error message:
      <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
      <html><head>
      <title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
      </head><body>
      <h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
```

The Web Connector is hitting your server, and your server is returning a "301 Moved Permanently" response instead of a "200 OK" response like it should be.

Are you *100% positive* that your AppURL is correct?

Can you actually post your AppURL, so that we can verify that it's correct?

Comment: Thanks keith i resolved the issue & yes app url was incorrect